# Numexpr error when importing Pandas in ST2

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, sublimetext2, anaconda

I recently created my own build file for ST2 so that I could utilize the Anaconda install of python (and all of its packages i.e. pandas).   Everything seems to work except I am getting the error below from the following code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 3), index=index, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
print df
```

I get the following output:

```
/Users/myname/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numexpr/cpuinfo.py:50: UserWarning: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
  stacklevel=stacklevel+1)
/Users/myname/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numexpr/cpuinfo.py:71: UserWarning: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
  stacklevel=stacklevel+1):
                   A         B         C
2000-01-01 -1.548053 -0.151756  0.118057
2000-01-02 -0.882342  0.910580 -0.063268
2000-01-03  0.376109 -1.185223  0.285832
2000-01-04 -1.723744 -0.006433  0.075403
2000-01-05  2.074607  0.464006  0.985860
2000-01-06 -0.174024  1.164324 -1.715245
2000-01-07 -1.396297 -2.066237 -0.236335
2000-01-08  1.148892  1.083617 -0.846928
```

To test numexpr I tried:

```
import numexpr
numexpr.test()
```

It ran in both ST2 using my build and in the terminal using Anaconda's python(produced 'OK').
I am working on OSX 10.9.4, with Python 2.7.8, Anaconda 2.1.0.
Appreciate any suggestions - Thanks

Updated to show versions:

```
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 2.7.8.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Darwin
OS-release: 13.3.0
machine: x86_64
processor: 
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: None

pandas: 0.14.1
nose: 1.3.4
Cython: 0.21
numpy: 1.9.0
scipy: 0.14.0
statsmodels: 0.5.0
IPython: 2.3.0
sphinx: 1.2.3
patsy: 0.3.0
scikits.timeseries: None
dateutil: 1.5
pytz: 2014.7
bottleneck: None
tables: 3.1.1
numexpr: 2.3.1
matplotlib: 1.4.0
openpyxl: 1.8.5
xlrd: 0.9.3
xlwt: 0.7.5
xlsxwriter: 0.5.7
lxml: 3.4.0
bs4: 4.3.2
html5lib: None
httplib2: None
apiclient: None
rpy2: None
sqlalchemy: 0.9.7
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
```

Comment: Can you run `pd.show_versions()` and [edit] the results into your question? It's possible you're not running the latest versions of everything, and that might be causing the bug.

Comment: [`numexpr`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numexpr) is currently at version 2.4. You might want to try upgrading it. Also, it may or may not be relevant to the problem at hand, but [`dateutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-dateutil/2.2) is now at 2.2, so you might want to upgrade that as well, especially because you're using datetimes in your DF.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.   Unfortunately those are the most up to date packages from the Anaconda install.

Answer (score 3):

This is an error from the routine which parse the std output of various standard UNIX commands. Make sure you have  '/usr/sbin/' in your PATH unix environment variable. This small fix solved problem on my mac os (Yosemite with Anaconda/Python).